# $http GET request not reaching server from AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, http, get, angular-http

I have a REST API deployed on localhost with the following GET endpoint: `localhost:9000/get-events/1`

This endpoint is returning the correct response when I send the request through Postman or through a web browser. It also contains CORS headers etc, and I have also handled the options requests with appropriate headers. (The server is implemented in Play Framework).

The response from Postman for the above GET request is:

headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Content-Length →34
Content-Security-Policy →default-src 'self'
Content-Type →application/json
Date →Tue, 10 Apr 2018 04:50:16 GMT
Referrer-Policy →origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-Frame-Options →DENY
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies →master-only
X-XSS-Protection →1; mode=block
```

body:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "events": "[<some list....>]"
}
```

I basically want the list that is being returned by the server to be loaded in a ng-repeat list in my Event List page when the user is navigating to it. I have implemented this in my code like this:

inside the controller in `app.js`:

```
$scope.getlist = function() {
    $http({
        url: 'localhost:9000/get-events/1',
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log('SUCCESS: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
        $scope.events = JSON.parse(response.data.events);
    }, function (response) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    });
}
```

and in the front end, `index.html`:

```
<a href="eventList.html" ng-click="getlist()">Fetch List</a>
```

and, `eventList.html`:

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="event in events">{{event.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

When I click on the link, it gives the following error in the browser's console:

```
ERROR: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"localhost:9000/get-events/1","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}
```

from the server logs, it seems that the request is not reaching the server at all.

The strange thing is that I am also sending a POST request to the same server, while doing the user login and that request is successfully reaching the server and correctly giving the response from the angularJS app.

This is how I call the POST from my angularjs controller:

```
$scope.login = function () {
    console.log('login called');
    var loginURL = 'localhost:9000/login';
    var loginInfo = {
        'email': $scope.email,
        'password': $scope.password
    };
    $http({
        url: loginURL,
        method: 'POST',
        data: loginInfo,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }).then(function successLogin(response) {
        console.log('SUCCESS: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    }, function failLogin(response) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    });
}
```

What am I missing while doing the GET request?

Answer (score 0):

In the server have you added CORS header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in server end ?

Comment: yes it is there in the server, I also verified it as it is also coming in the response in Postman. Also, a POST request to the same server is working from the angularJS code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Its Working for me

    try this.

    html:
     <a  ng-click="getlist()">Fetch List</a>

    js:

     $scope.getlist = function () {
                $http({
                    url: 'ControllerName/getevents/1',
                    method: 'GET'
                }).then(function (response) {
                    console.log('SUCCESS: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
                }, function (response) {
                    console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
                });
            }

output in console:

SUCCESS: {"data":"","status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"Employee/getevents/1","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"OK","xhrStatus":"complete"}
```

Comment: So, this didn't work, but I tried a couple things which worked. Thanks for your answer though! :)

Comment: Ok @sumit Keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was running my Angular App using Firefox earlier and I just thought of using Google Chrome. It helped me by providing this extra information in the console:

`Failed to load localhost:9000/volunteer-events/1: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

So, it seems that in the HTTP get URL I was just using `localhost:9000...` instead of the complete `http://localhost:9000...`

changing my URL to `http://localhost:9000...` fixed the problem.

Answering this here so that anyone else who was stuck on this for long time like me would benefit from it!

Although I am still not sure how it worked for the POST ?